# Firebase authenticate as admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way I can authenticate with Firebase as an administrator of a firebase for full read/write access to it (already has security rules protecting parts of it), or will I have to write a security rule that somehow allows me access to the full firebase, for example by providing a certain password/key.

Is there a standard or suggested way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See this for the 'latest' documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCustomToken)

authWithCustomToken is now signInWithCustomToken (firebase version 3.x)

Example from the documentation:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-custom-token') {
        alert('The token you provided is not valid.');
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I see this is the regular auth to connect to firebase (java, ios js etc.). How can I do this in Python (I mean how can I sign in as an admin). How can I make sure that whoever is using my admin program is really an admin?

Answer (score 51):

Andrew's answer will only work if you're authenticating outside your client-side code (otherwise you shouldn't be using your `MY_SECRET` obviously).  Since many people, like myself, use Firebase to avoid server code, here's an alternate answer.

In most firebase apps you probably have a "Users" object in addition to your simple login "auth" object (which only stores email and password).  You can add an "isAdmin" or "isModerator" (or whatever you want) to each $user in the "Users" object.

And then your rules would look like this (assuming your auth.id matches your $user key):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "someObject": {
      ".write": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just starting out with Firebase and I really like your suggestion, but shouldn't it be `child(auth.uid)`?  Just curious.. like I said, still learning :)

Comment: Yep @BenjaminSolum you're right, auth.uid is the new auth.id.  Firebase completely removed auth.id which was only unique to the provider and replaced it with a globally unique id.  I updated it in the answer, hopefully it will works as a whole.

Comment: Any advice on which equality operator to use, i.e. `.val() == true` or `.val() === true`?

Comment: Adding that I think it's better to have a separate `administrators` list rather than having an isAdmin property. This is so that we could have a security that only admins can add or remove users from the `administrators` list.

Comment: How do you trust that only admins can set isAdmin to true?

Comment: @SethLadd Wouldn't it be with a specific rule for the isAdmin object?

Comment: I believe this solution is not secure, as the validation for the variable is done on JS client-side and it (the validation) may be easily manipulated

Comment: @davidtaubmann I know this is over a year old but this isn't client side, this is the rules JSON object that Firebase uses to determine who has access to what.

Answer (score 18):

Yes there is. You simply need to authenticate using a Firebase Secret instead of an authentication token. ie.

```
firebaseRef.auth(MY_SECRET);
```

You can find the Secret in the Authentication section of Forge.

Comment: `auth()` is now depricated. Refer Matt's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27413337/978501

Comment: I used ref.authWithCustomToken(), but the payload that is returned has null properties: auth, expires, token, uid. Except for the 'provider' property which is set to 'custom'. What's the reason for this??

Comment: @nodebase response (authData) is `Object {auth: null, expires: null, token: "", uid: null, provider: "custom"}` but it works against rule `".read": "auth.admin == true"`

Answer (score 15):

[As per the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithcustomtoken.html), you need to use `firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken`.

Example;

```
firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(FIREBASE_SECRET, function(error, authData) {
  if(!error) {
    // You are authenticated
  }
});
```

`firebaseRef.auth` is now deprecated, use `firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken` instead.

Comment: response is (authData) `Object {auth: null, expires: null, token: "", uid: null, provider: "custom"}` but it works against rule `".read": "auth.admin == true"`

Comment: How is this safe? doesn't that mean you will hard-code your secret in the client app?