# How Firebase can authorise user as admin?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

Maybe I wasn't searching the documentation properly, but what is the recommended standard way of treating authorisation levels/classification for admin users in firebase?

Let's say in classic admin user scenario, where admin should have the access to all user accounts while normal authenticated users have write access to only specific objects.

I came accross [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607101/firebase-authenticate-as-admin) but the solution using firebase secret is not good enough in this case. Firebase secret is meant to be used by server and setting up the extra server authenticating admin users and talking to firebase is certainly the option, but the complexity and programming overhead is increased.

[The better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22924908/2232045) is using the security rules. Question here is - Does not this generate an extra overhead for each single read/write operation? The number of general users could be in millions while there is only handful of admins. Secondly you do not want non admin to be authenticated by management tool even though they will not be authorised to do anything.

Third option - however I don't know how would I achieve this - limit authentication to admin interface webapp only to specific admin users or set the limit for the specific domain. Let's say only {name}@myappadmin.com will be allowed to be authenticated thus I will not need to do the authorisation check before each operation.  Is this even possible using only Firebase as backend?

Comment: Check out this example of implementing role-based security with Firebase security rules: https://gist.github.com/sararob/331760829a9dcb4be3e7

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it about how to create admin users, about the performance of security rules, or about creating user roles? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Kato now it is mostly about the performance of security rules. Basically having some cumbersome condition in rule which needs to be evaluated each single time a normal user access the database.